# Convert a whole list to string

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

raw_data = {'a': ['a'],'b':['b'],'c':['c'],'d':[['a','b']]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['a','b','c','d'])
```

this results,

```
    a   b     c        d
0   a   b    c       [a, b]
```

then i'm adding it into a single column like this
`df['test'] = df['a']+'+'+df['b']+'+'+df['c']`

df['test'] gives `a+b+c`

After that I'm fetching each single value using this

```
finalArr = df['test'][0]
finalArr = finalArr.split("+")
one = finalArr[0]
two = finalArr[1]
three = finalArr[2]
```

How to add df['d'] to this :

`df['test'] = df['a']+'+'+df['b']+'+'+df['c']`

and fetch `four = finalArr[3]`

expected output :

```
df['test'] 

a+b+c+[a,b]


four = finalArr[3]
[a,b]


[a,b] should be in list format while fetching
```

Comment: Please add the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Use, [`Dataframe.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) on axis `1` to join the columns `a, b, c` around seperator `+` then use [`Series.str.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html) to join the list then concatenate it with square brackets:

```
df['test'] =  df[['a', 'b', 'c']].agg('+'.join, axis=1) + '+[' + df['d'].str.join(',') + ']'
```

---

```
# print(df)
   a  b  c       d         test
0  a  b  c  [a, b]  a+b+c+[a,b]
```

Comment: @D.S.D Edited the answer.

Comment: You could not be able to concat list with the string, its not possible. Please rethink what you are trying to do. You can use `finalArr[3].strip('[]').split(',')` to get the list.

Comment: @D.S.D If this answered your question you may accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Python program to convert a list to string 

# Function to convert 
def listToString(s): 

    # initialize an empty string 
    str1 = "" 

    # traverse in the string 
    for ele in s: 
        str1 += ele 

    # return string 
    return str1 


# Driver code    
s = ['Geeks', 'for', 'Geeks'] 
print(listToString(s))
```

Comment: Edited the question please check

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use this line **string=[str(value) for value in df.iloc[0,:]]**

```
 import pandas as pd

 raw_data = {'a': ['a'],'b':['b'],'c':['c'],'d':[['a','b']]}
 df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['a','b','c','d'])

 string=[str(value) for value in df.iloc[0,:]]
 df['test']=pd.Series({0:string})
 print(string[3])

 "['a', 'b']"
```

Comment: Edited the question please check

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
s = '[' + df['d'].str.join(', ') + ']' #first convert your list to a string
df['test'][0] += '+' + s               #then add it to your variable
```

The result will be:

```
>>>print(df['test'][0])
"a+b+c+[a, b]"
```

And then if you want to fetch it as a list, you can use this:

```
arr = df['test'][0].split('+')
arr[3] = arr[3][1:-1].split(', ') #convert the string to a list. 
# [1: -1] removes the brackets ('[', ']')
# you can also use .strip('[]') instead
```

Good luck with your project ;)

Comment: Edited the question please check